# How to implement multithreading for web scraping?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multithreading, web-scraping

My problem seems simple and I don't know how to solve it.

I have a program that look like this:

```
def webscrape(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    data = json.loads(data)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data['dataProvider'])
    return df
```

I would like to apply this function for multiple sites:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for url in urls:
    df = pd.concat([df, webscrape(url)], axis=1)
```

I would like to accelerate my program with multithreading but I don't know how I should start.

Answer (score 1):

To accelerate your program with multithreading, you can use the `concurrent.futures` module in Python. This module provides a high-level interface for asynchronously executing callables (functions or methods) using threads or processes. In your case, you can use the `ThreadPoolExecutor` from `concurrent.futures` to parallelize the web scraping process.
Here's how you can modify your code to use multithreading:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

def webscrape(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    data = json.loads(data)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data['dataProvider'])
    return df

def scrape_all_sites(urls):
    dfs = []
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        # Submit the tasks to the executor and store the future objects
        futures = [executor.submit(webscrape, url) for url in urls]

        # Gather the results from the completed futures
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            df = future.result()
            dfs.append(df)

    # Concatenate all dataframes into one
    result_df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
    return result_df

# Assuming you have a list of URLs called 'urls'
result_df = scrape_all_sites(urls)
```

If you need add workers, Here's how you can set the `max_workers` option in the `scrape_all_sites` function:

```py
def scrape_all_sites(urls, max_workers=None):
    dfs = []
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as executor:
        # Rest of the code remains unchanged
        # ...
```

When calling the `scrape_all_sites` function, you can specify the `max_workers` argument to determine the number of threads:

```py
# Assuming you have a list of URLs called 'urls'
result_df = scrape_all_sites(urls, max_workers=4)  # Set max_workers as desired
```

Comment: it seems that ThreadPoolExecutor has option max_workers. How should I input this number ?

Comment: I'm happy that this answer has been of use to you. If you think it's the right solution, please mark it as correct. I can't write code directly in the comments, so I'll edit my previous answer and add additional codes.

Comment: how should I fix the max_workers number ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point clearly, but you can modify the number by simply changing the value you entered.

For instance:
`If max_workers=1, it represents one worker.` but 
`If max_workers=4, it represents four workers.`
Feel free to adjust it as you wish.

Comment: I mean what's the difference if I input 1, 4, 100 or 1000...????

Comment: The number of workers (threads) can greatly affect how well concurrent tasks perform and how efficiently they run. To optimize this, you should choose an appropriate value based on the amount of data and the resources available on your computer.
I think 1 or 2 is best, If you have a large number of cases use 4.